# Не вызывается метод

Tags: php

При пустых полях выводится "Empty query!", а то что должна вывести функция admin_login() отсутствует, почему так?

При вызове метода admin_login() из другого файла отображаются оба echo, при вызове внутри файла отображается только 'tets'.

```
define('LOGIN_HTML', '/var/user/data/www/site.ru/html/login.html');

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    if(!empty($login) && !empty($password)) {
        _login($login, $password);
    }
    else {
        admin_login();
        echo 'Empty query!';
    }
}

function admin_login() {
    echo 'test';
    echo file_get_contents(LOGIN_HTML);
}

function _login($l, $p) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: А пробовали вывести в `admin_login()` что то другое? Или файл пустой в `LOGIN_HTML` Попробуйте задать  `echo 'file_get_contents(LOGIN_HTML)';`

Comment: Уверены, что admin_login() действительно выводит что-то? Попробуйте вызвать её отдельно и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: @Александр в общем если вызывать метод из другого файла то все отображается, если добавить в метод echo 'test'; то test выводится а остальное нет... как так

Comment: Значит пусть к фалу не правильный. Проверьте.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov путь к файлу правильный, и при вызове из другого файла все работает

Comment: Я понял! все банально, как обычно, константа вне зоны видимости при работе только с этим файлом